# Grabbing specific variable from while loop for form submit

Tags: php, mysql

I have a while loop generating information with a checkbox, I would like to update the database with the new "completed" value. How can I select the specific checkbox that is generated. Please help with showing me how I can grab the specific value of a checkbox and the task_name.

Thanks, Ryan

```
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $task_name = $row['task_name'] ;
        $task_description = $row['task_description'];
        $task_completed = $row['completed'];
        $tasks .= '<div id="tasksBody">
                    <form action="" method="post">Completed? <input name="completed" type="checkbox" '.
                    ($task_completed == 1?'checked="checked"':'').
                    ' /><input type="submit" value="Update"><br /><br />
                    <b>'.$task_name.'</b><br /><br />'.$task_description.'<hr><br /></form></div>';
        }
}
echo $tasks;
```

Comment: what do you want to do?please explain more.

Answer (score 0):

You need to name your input with something unique for the row, such as the task_name, or better, a database record ID.

Then when the user submits the form, you will use $_POST["YourTaskNameOrIDHere"] to check the value.

What you have currently calls all the check boxes the same thing.

---

EDIT: I'm sorry, you're isolating all of these in their own forms, I just realized that. 
What you can add is an `<input type="hidden" value="$task_name" name="TaskName" />` to the form, so you can look what the checkbox is corresponding to. Then, when the user submits the form, use $_POST["TaskName"] to find out the name of the task.

Comment: Where and how would i do this? @Barrakoda

Comment: @Ryan please see my revised edit. I misunderstood what you were doing at first.

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden field to each of your forms containing the `task_id`

```
<form action="" method="post">
    Completed? 
    <input name="completed" type="checkbox" <?=($task_completed == 1?'checked="checked"':'')?> value="1" />
    ...
    <input name="task_id" value="<?=$task_id"?> type="hidden" />**strong text**
</form>
```

After submit:

```
if (isset($_POST['task_id']) { // form has been submitted

    $task_id = $_POST['task_id'];
    $completed = $_POST['completed'];

    $sql = "UPDATE task SET task_completed=$completed WHERE task_id=$task_id LIMIT 1";
    // code for updating database
    // better use PDO or mysqli-* instead of old and deprecated mysql_*
}
```